# Pulse animation effect to MGLCircleStyleLayer Mapbox ios

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I am updating `CircleLayer` radius property value continuously with the `ValueAnimator` like this in Android:

```
ValueAnimator circleLayerAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofObject(
                new FloatEvaluator(),
                15f, 30f
        );
        circleLayerAnimator.setDuration(1000);
        circleLayerAnimator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
        circleLayerAnimator.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
        circleLayerAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {

                attractions.setProperties(
                        circleRadius((Float) animator.getAnimatedValue())
                );
            }

        });
        circleLayerAnimator.start();
```

How can I do this with `MGLCircleStyleLayer` in ios swift? Should I use `NSTimer` for updating layer radius value or any other property in mapbox like Android?

Comment: Are you asking like this? https://www.google.com/search?biw=1440&bih=720&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=v2kkXP_KOYjcvAS_3ajYBw&q=pulse+effect+gif&oq=pulse+effect+gif&gs_l=img.3..0.1152.2773..3109...0.0..0.131.424.2j2......1....1..gws-wiz-img.......0i30j0i8i30j0i5i30j0i24.fvKW2wNB-Ak#imgrc=I5pCc70LDATR5M:

Comment: Yes, something like that. Same like current location marker animation but I need for Circle layer

Comment: You can try https://github.com/shu223/Pulsator

Comment: Sorry but I think you did not get my question. I want to change radius or all visible circle layer. And also we can not add sublayer to `MGLCircleStyleLayer`. Check my Android code in question. Maybe I can use `circleRadiusTransition` but not sure how to use it

Comment: @DhavalGolakiya Take a look at these: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/3039 and https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/c35f18fdbc94917c20cb675b6510c9feaed40f0c/platform/ios/MGLMapView.mm#L3071-L3095

Comment: @HastiRanjkesh The links you posted here are for AnnotationsView and I am asking for MGLCircleStyleLayer